# Form background color does not change in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to set background color to a Form in SwiftUI and its not working.

```
struct CustomFormView: View {
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var desc: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)
                    TextField("Notes: (Optional)", text: $desc)
                        .padding(.bottom, 100)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("New Session")
            }
            .background(Color.red)
        }
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}

struct CustomFormView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomFormView()
    }
}
```

Its always white. :|

I am using Xcode 14.3

Can someone please help me fix it ?

Comment: You are not setting a background color to the form.

Comment: You can use `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .red` for example to set the `Form`'s background color to red. This can go in the `init` of the view, however this affects _every_ `List` and `Form`. Alternatively, you could use [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to customise a single one by doing something like `.introspectTableView { $0.backgroundColor = .red }`.

Comment: @ElTomato I have tried `.background(Color.red) under the Form as well

Comment: @ILuvProgramming I made it into an answer - if you have any questions, just ask and it should be easy to fix.

Comment: @George_E do you know I can fix it ? can you please check ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .red` for example to set the `Form`'s background color to red. This can go in the `init` of the view, however this affects *every* `List` and `Form`.

Alternatively, you could use [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to customise a single one by doing something like:

```
.introspectTableView { $0.backgroundColor = .red }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you.
I tried this on Form. and it worked partially. I still have a issue where form has some white overlay

```
struct FormSampleView: View {
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var desc: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Text("Hello")
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                TextField("Notes: (Optonal)", text: $desc)
                    .padding(.bottom, 100)
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            .accentColor(.blue)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            })
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct FormSampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FormSampleView()
    }
}
```

[image]